# Replace the Xubuntu 11.10 splash screen

Tags: 11.10, xubuntu

I'd like to be able to replace the Xubuntu 11.10 splash screen that I see on boot with another splash screen that does not have an indicator meter of progress. 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes,

the boot splash is handled by Plymouth, any Plymouth theme should work.

To install a Plymouth theme, you can do this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /lib/plymouth/themes/mytheme/mytheme.plymouth 100
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: does this work for ubuntu 11.10??

Comment: What about for Xubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to disable the Xubuntu splash screen on startup and when shutting down, I found the following working for me in Xubuntu 11.10;

1. open Thunar (your file manager) as administrator;

   - Open a terminal screen
   - There type "sudo thunar" (and press enter)
2. With the Thunar as root 'as root' now open,

   - Navigate to /lib/plymouth/themes
   - Select and cut the two files default.playmouth and text.playmounth
   - Paste them somewhere in a backup directory, e.g. /lib/plymouth/themes/backup

Done!

Comment: What about for Xubuntu 18.04?